# Apache Spark: Memory Footprint of an Uncached Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My application reads a data frame from parquet and runs it through a series of ml transformers where each transformer uses the `withColumn` function to add a column to the data frame. The resulting data frame is written back to parquet. All this process happens within one stage with 200 tasks (same as the number of partitions in the original data frame)

I'm not caching any of the data frames, and indeed, the Storage tab in the web UI is empty. Still, the worker nodes (30G memory each) slowly consume more and more memory throughout the run, until finally tasks start failing. On the worker logs I see the message below (which I'm assuming relates to memory issues).

> INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20160615090601-0007/665 finished with
>   state EXITED message Command exited with code 137 exitStatus 137

Is this behavior expected? If I'm not persisting anything, why doesn't Spark write the output to parquet and releases memory during the run? What should be the memory footprint of a data frame that's not persisted in any way?

Note: I turned on GC logging and I don't see any unusual behavior around the time the tasks are failing (just some allocation failures here and there, throughout the run.)